Drizzle Expo SQLite: NOT NULL Constraint Fails on Runtime Functions
I'm having an issue with Drizzle ORM and Expo SQLite in my project. I’m getting this error:
[Error: Calling the 'runAsync' function has failed
→ Caused by: Error code 19: NOT NULL constraint failed: exercises.id]

This error occurs when trying to insert a new record into the db, on all fields with runtime functions, like id, createdAt, and updatedAt.
import { createId } from '@paralleldrive/cuid2';
import { sqliteTable, text } from 'drizzle-orm/sqlite-core';

export const exercise = sqliteTable('exercises', {
  id: text('id')
    .primaryKey()
    .$defaultFn(() => createId()),
  name: text('name').notNull().unique(),
  createdAt: text('created_at')
    .$defaultFn(() => new Date().toISOString())
    .notNull(),
  updatedAt: text('updated_at')
    .$defaultFn(() => new Date().toISOString())
    .$onUpdateFn(() => new Date().toISOString())
    .notNull(),
});

It seems like the functions aren't running before the constraints are checked. Has anyone else run into this? Any tips or fixes?
